# How to mock a method returning OneOf<IServiceA, IServiceB>? Using Moq

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, moq

In my project, a common method of service resolver class is written. In which a public method returns OneOf<IServiceA, IServiceB, IServiceC>. I am not able to mock this class behavior.

```
private readonly IServiceA _serviceA;
private readonly IServiceB _serviceB;
private readonly IServiceC _serviceC;

public ProjectResolver(
    IServiceA serviceA,
    IServiceB serviceB,
    IServiceC serviceC
)
{
    _serviceA = serviceA;
    _serviceB = serviceB;
    _serviceC = serviceC;
}
```

...

```
public OneOf<IServiceA, IServiceB, IServiceC> GetServiceHandler(string Id)
{
    if (!_projectSettings.Projects.ContainsKey(Id))
        return new NotFound();

    return _projectSettings.Projects[Id] switch
    {
        "a" => (ServiceA)_serviceA,
        "b" => (ServiceB)_serviceB,
        "c" => (ServiceC)_serviceC,
        _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(Id)
    };
}
```

I have mocked all the services (IServiceA, IServiceB and IServiceC) and the project resolver class. While running tests I am getting below exception.

```
Exception while calling Path
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Castle.Proxies.IserviceA' to type 'ServiceA'.
```

I need help in mocking this projectResolver class. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide a full [mre]. Currently I don't see any usage of Mock.

Comment: https://github.com/mcintyre321/OneOf/issues/63

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mock or not - you should not cast to explicit service implementation anyway. Create the `OneOf` "manually":

```cs
return _projectSettings.Projects[Id] switch
{
    "a" => OneOf<IServiceA, IServiceB, IServiceC>.FromT0(_serviceA),
    "b" => OneOf<IServiceA, IServiceB, IServiceC>.FromT1(_serviceB),
    "c" => OneOf<IServiceA, IServiceB, IServiceC>.FromT2(_serviceC),
    _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(Id)
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Guru Stron. This was the issue, and I was looking somewhere else the whole time. Thanks 